# Different size in Interface Builder and simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

My app shows different sizes in simulator than Interface Builder. Is there a way to set that the simulator will show same as interface builder? I need it so that the all labels and `imageViews` stay in same positions as they are currently in interface builder. Is there a way to do it like that? I have many multiple classes and i had to set a lot of coordinates so I don't want to redo it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see following link link it will help you

[AutoLayout](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_8_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder)

[www.techotopia.com](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_8_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder)